# Regex matching everything before the question mark

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter

Alright, I'm attempting to rewrite a URL in .htaccess

Right now the URL looks like this:

```
http://host.com/catalog/search/item/465?item=465
```

I want it to look like

```
http://host.com/catalog/search/item/465
```

My rewrite is the following, which seems to work on [regex tester](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=search/item/%28%5B%5E?%5D%2b%29&input=http://host.com/catalog/search/item/465?item=465):

```
RewriteRule search/item/([^?]+) http://host.com/catalog/search/item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But instead I get:

```
"This page isn't redirecting properly."
```

Comment: Don't you have an endless loop here? You haven't bounded the match part of the rule, so whenever it finds "search/item" anywhere in the URL, the rule is going to fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

everything till the first "?"

```
(^.*)?\?
```

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have said "up to but not including"

Comment: In fact, your $1 is just what the expression get before the first "?". But this can give what you want! ;) `(^.*)(?=\?)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)\?.* $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I may be using it incorrectly, but that matches the entire path for me.

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(.*)%5C%3F.*&input=http%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%2Fitem%2F465%3Fitem%3D465